# modelName is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new in node js. Please helm me out. In the following code "modelName" is a variable which may be changed in each function call but it is showing me error that "modelName" is undefined. Thanks

```
"createModel": function(modelName, callback) {
    app.models.modelName.create(self.modelName(), function(error, modelInstance) {
        if(!error){
            callback(null, modelInstance.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you referring to the app.models.**modelName** or the self.**modelName**() reference?  Either way, those are completely different references than the **modelName** parameter you are defining in the function signature (modelName, callback).

If I read your question correctly, you are trying to access a property dynamically based on the modelName that is passed in.  If so, you can't use dot notation, try something like this:

```
"createModel": function(modelName, callback) {
    app.models[modelName].create(self[modelName](), function (error, modelInstance) {
        if(!error){
            callback(null, modelInstance.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, you understood my question correctly and your solution is working fine... thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

```
"createModel": function(modelName, callback) {
    app.models[modelName].create(self.modelName(), function(error, modelInstance) {
        if(!error){
            callback(null, modelInstance.id);
        }
    });
}
```

You need to access dynamic properties with bracket notation instead of dot notation.